# Statistics-Proof for step deviation method

Tags: statistics

I am a tenth standard student and have been recently studying the ways to find mean
I came across a method

Step deviation method

No proof is mentioned in the book and i cannot find it on google. I tried it myself.

I think that it maybe assosciated with the property that the

$\sum_{i=0}^n= {mean-x_i} =0$

So can someone help me with the proof of step deviation method

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. The 'step deviation' method I learnt in school was to define a new variable $u_i=(x_i-a)/b$ (for suitable $a,b$) that helped to find mean,variance of $x_i$ in terms of those of $u_i$ in certain situations.

Comment: Yes that one only. The expression i mentioned is only a guess that i have made to prove

Comment: What do you want to prove?

Comment: I want to prove the step deviation method to find mean

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. If you want to find mean of $x$ in terms of that of $u$, then that is straightforward.

Comment: Yes i know the method but i want the reason why it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a dataset $\mathcal{D} = \{ x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n \} $, we transform it, using suitable $A$ and $h$ to
$\mathcal{D}' = \{ (x_1-A)/h, (x_2-A)/h, \cdots , (x_n -A)/h\} =  \{ u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_n \}   $
Let frequencies respectively be $\{f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_n\}$. 
Then the step deviation method is: $$\bar x =  A + \dfrac{h \sum u_if_i}{\sum f_i} $$

---

### Derivation

Let the dataset be $\mathcal{D}_{orig} = \{ x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n \} $, with frequencies $f_i$ and let's call the mean $\bar x_{orig}$

We assume a mean $A$, that is close to the expected value.

That is, we transform the dataset to: $\mathcal{D}_{1} = \{ x_1-A, x_2-A, \cdots , x_n -A\} = \{ d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_n \} $, and we have $\bar d = \bar x-A$

Next, we divide each of the new terms by $h$, to get
$$\mathcal{D}_{2} = \{ (x_1-A)/h, (x_2-A)/h, \cdots , (x_n -A)/h\} =  \{ d_1/h, d_2/h, \cdots, d_n/h \} = \{ u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_n \}   $$ and thus $\bar u = \bar d/h = (\bar x-A)/h$

That is, we have $\bar x = \bar u *h + A$

---

If frequencies are $f_i$, we have $\bar u = \dfrac{\sum u_if_i}{\sum f_i}$

Thus overall, we have $\bar x =  A + \dfrac{h \sum u_if_i}{\sum f_i} $